# Django: "UserProfileRole.userProfile" must be a "UserProfile" instance

Tags: python, django

I'm having a strange riddle to solve:

I extended my django-1.4 user-objects with a UserProfile, as described at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/ and wanted to implement project-specific roles. So my models look like the following:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
   projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, through='UserProjectRole')
   [...]

class UserProjectRole(models.Model):
   userProfile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
   project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
   group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
   [...]
```

I needed to pass a css-class, so I created a model-form for UserProjectRole and implemented the userProfile-Field with a widget:

```
class ProjectRoleForm(forms.ModelForm):
   userProfile = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='Users',
      queryset=UserProfile.objects.all(),
      widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'select-multiple'}))

   class Meta:
       model = UserProjectRole
```

The form is presented correctly, however, it's crashing during save-process with the following error

```
Cannot assign "[<UserProfile: MyUser>]": "UserProjectRole.userProfile" must be a "UserProfile" instance.
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is it's because you are using a **forms.SelectMultiple** widget. Which gives you a list of UserProfile instances ( `[<UserProfile: MyUser>]` ) and not a single **UserProfile** instance which is of course required to set on a **ForeignKey** field (*UserProjectRole.userProfile*). Thus I suggest to try using a [**forms.Select**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Select) widget instead.

Comment: Argh, guess i made a logical mistake trying to assign many users to one role using a single entity. Ouch, i'll check that.